# Small String Optimisation (Debug vs Release mode)

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, compiler-optimization

I've been examining the small string optimisation (in MSVC 2019) using this sample script:

```cpp
#include <string>

void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    std::printf("global op new called, size = %zu\n", size);
    void* ptr = std::malloc(size);

    if (ptr)
        return ptr;
    else
        throw std::bad_alloc{};
}

int main()
{
    std::string test = "small value";
    return 0;
}
```

Note, I took `void* operator new(size_t size)` from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new.

In *Release* mode the optimisation works as expected (i.e. `new` does not get called), but in *Debug* mode the script actually prints `global op new called, size = 16`. After drilling down this seems to be due to this code segment in header `xmemory`:

```cpp
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 0
  #define _GET_PROXY_ALLOCATOR(_Alty, _Al) _Fake_allocator()
  template <class _Alloc>
  using _Container_proxy_ptr = _Fake_proxy_ptr_impl;
#else // _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 0
  #define _GET_PROXY_ALLOCATOR(_Alty, _Al) static_cast<_Rebind_alloc_t<_Alty, _Container_proxy>>(_Al)
  template <class _Alloc>
  using _Container_proxy_ptr = _Container_proxy_ptr12<_Rebind_alloc_t<_Alloc, _Container_proxy>>;
#endif // _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 0
```

We can see that in *Release* mode (i.e. `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 0`) we use `_Fake_proxy_ptr_impl`, whereas in *Debug* mode we use `_Container_proxy_ptr12` which uses `new`.

---

My question is simple: why is there this difference between *Debug* and *Release* mode?

Comment: *My question is simple: why is there this difference between Debug and Release mode?* -- I don't understand why you expected Debug to be the same as Release mode.  There are many other things in the Visual Studio compiler where Debug mode differs from Release, such as iterator checking, checking for valid strict-weak-orderings, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's my question, if they are different, then why are they different?

Comment: The term "Debug" in this case is that *optimizations are turned off* .  Nothing stops you from going into the Debug settings and turning on the optimizations for the "Debug" setting.  Then of course, your debugger line will jump all over the place instead of being placed on the line you expect.  Similarly, you can turn off optimizations in "Release".

Comment: In a nutshell: Unoptimized debug builds are easy to debug, but are slow. Optimized release builds are hard to debug, but are fast.

Comment: I think the difference is in the approach that Microsoft has taken. In standard C++ there is no difference to the headers for debug or release. For instance, sizeof(std::string) is 32 on GCC. However, it is 40 for debug on MSVC and 32 for Release! So, this means that you cannot even link a debug compiled object with a release one, otherwise you'd probably end up with a segmentation fault!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small string optimization is still there also in Debug mode.
If we create a larger `string`

```
std::string test = "large value.large value.large value.large value.";
```

then we get the actual `string` allocation

```
global op new called, size = 64
```

in both Debug and Release builds.

What you're observing is the allocation of the container proxy for [iterator debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/debug-iterator-support?view=vs-2019) (as can be seen from `#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`)

```
struct _Container_proxy { // store head of iterator chain and back pointer
```

You can disable iterator debugging by building with `/D _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0` (but then it will be disabled for all containers, so also for `vector`, `map` etc.).